# Limiting Users Authenticated with Dante Socks

Tags: linux, proxy, dante

I have setup Dante proxy server, and it works OK.
Authentication method is been set to use local defined users.

Here is the sample of the configuration file.

```
 user.privileged: root
 user.unprivileged: nobody
 internal: 1.2.3.4 port= 1080
 external: 10.1.2.1
 socksmethod: username
 clientmethod: none

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}
```

what I'm looking is to limit each user with two concurrent logins and no more than that.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sinai No Not Yet.

Answer (score 0):

Late response but people searching this in the future:

Following the dante docs you can use

> **session.state.max**

to limit a session per ip. In addition, there is

> **session.max**

that limits the total number of concurrent sessions that exist concurently.

https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/session.html

Comment: hi. but by this you are not limiting the user itself. you just limit the ip address of the user. incase if you have more than one user at a same place, then all will be limited.

Comment: **session.state.key** you should read the link it has all the information you need.